# Problem with Kubernetes in Google Cloud stuck with ContainerCreating status

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm having a problem with my GKE cluster, all the pods are stuck with ContainerCreating status. When I run the kubectl get events I see this error:

```
Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Anyone knows what the hell is happening? I can't find this solution anywhere.

**EDIT**
I saw this post https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44273 saying that the GKE instances that are small than the default google instance for GKE(n1-standard-1) can have network problems. So I changed my instances to the default type, but without success. Here are my node and pod descriptions:

```
Name:               gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-bgb6
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=n1-standard-1
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=pool-nodes-dev
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=southamerica-east1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=southamerica-east1-a
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-bgb6
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:27:47 -0300
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type                          Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                          ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  KernelDeadlock                False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 09:58:58 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:27:16 -0300   KernelHasNoDeadlock          kernel has no deadlock
  FrequentUnregisterNetDevice   False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 09:58:58 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:32:18 -0300   UnregisterNetDevice          node is functioning properly
  NetworkUnavailable            False   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:27:48 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:27:48 -0300   RouteCreated                 NodeController create implicit route
  OutOfDisk                     False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 09:59:03 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:27:47 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure                False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 09:59:03 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:27:47 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure                  False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 09:59:03 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:27:47 -0300   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure                   False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 09:59:03 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:27:47 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                         True    Fri, 28 Sep 2018 09:59:03 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:28:07 -0300   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.0.0.2
  ExternalIP:
  Hostname:    gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-bgb6
Capacity:
 cpu:                1
 ephemeral-storage:  98868448Ki
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             3787608Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                940m
 ephemeral-storage:  47093746742
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             2702168Ki
 pods:               110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 1e8e0ecad8f5cc7fb5851bc64513d40c
 System UUID:                1E8E0ECA-D8F5-CC7F-B585-1BC64513D40C
 Boot ID:                    971e5088-6bc1-4151-94bf-b66c6c7ee9a3
 Kernel Version:             4.14.56+
 OS Image:                   Container-Optimized OS from Google
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://17.3.2
 Kubelet Version:            v1.10.7-gke.2
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.10.7-gke.2
PodCIDR:                     10.0.32.0/24
ProviderID:                  gce://aditumpay/southamerica-east1-a/gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-bgb6
Non-terminated Pods:         (11 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                                                              CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                                                              ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  kube-system                event-exporter-v0.2.1-5f5b89fcc8-xsvmg                            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                fluentd-gcp-scaler-7c5db745fc-vttc9                               0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-sz8r8                                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                heapster-v1.5.3-75486b456f-sj7k8                                  138m (14%)    138m (14%)  301856Ki (11%)   301856Ki (11%)
  kube-system                kube-dns-788979dc8f-99xvh                                         260m (27%)    0 (0%)      110Mi (4%)       170Mi (6%)
  kube-system                kube-dns-788979dc8f-9sz2b                                         260m (27%)    0 (0%)      110Mi (4%)       170Mi (6%)
  kube-system                kube-dns-autoscaler-79b4b844b9-6s8x2                              20m (2%)      0 (0%)      10Mi (0%)        0 (0%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-bgb6    100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                kubernetes-dashboard-598d75cb96-6nhcd                             50m (5%)      100m (10%)  100Mi (3%)       300Mi (11%)
  kube-system                l7-default-backend-5d5b9874d5-8wk6h                               10m (1%)      10m (1%)    20Mi (0%)        20Mi (0%)
  kube-system                metrics-server-v0.2.1-7486f5bd67-fvddz                            53m (5%)      148m (15%)  154Mi (5%)       404Mi (15%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource  Requests        Limits
  --------  --------        ------
  cpu       891m (94%)      396m (42%)
  memory    817952Ki (30%)  1391392Ki (51%)
Events:     <none>
```

The other node:

```
Name:               gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-m7bz
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=n1-standard-1
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=pool-nodes-dev
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=southamerica-east1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=southamerica-east1-a
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-m7bz
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:05 -0300
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type                          Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                          ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  KernelDeadlock                False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 10:11:03 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:29:34 -0300   KernelHasNoDeadlock          kernel has no deadlock
  FrequentUnregisterNetDevice   False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 10:11:03 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:34:36 -0300   UnregisterNetDevice          node is functioning properly
  NetworkUnavailable            False   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:06 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:06 -0300   RouteCreated                 NodeController create implicit route
  OutOfDisk                     False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 10:11:49 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:05 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure                False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 10:11:49 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:05 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure                  False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 10:11:49 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:05 -0300   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure                   False   Fri, 28 Sep 2018 10:11:49 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:05 -0300   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                         True    Fri, 28 Sep 2018 10:11:49 -0300   Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:25 -0300   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.0.0.3
  ExternalIP:
  Hostname:    gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-m7bz
Capacity:
 cpu:                1
 ephemeral-storage:  98868448Ki
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             3787608Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                940m
 ephemeral-storage:  47093746742
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             2702168Ki
 pods:               110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 f1d5cf2a0b2c5472cf6509778a7941a7
 System UUID:                F1D5CF2A-0B2C-5472-CF65-09778A7941A7
 Boot ID:                    f35bebb8-acd7-4a2f-95d6-76604638aef9
 Kernel Version:             4.14.56+
 OS Image:                   Container-Optimized OS from Google
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://17.3.2
 Kubelet Version:            v1.10.7-gke.2
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.10.7-gke.2
PodCIDR:                     10.0.33.0/24
ProviderID:                  gce://aditumpay/southamerica-east1-a/gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-m7bz
Non-terminated Pods:         (7 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                                                              CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                                                              ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  default                    aditum-payment-7d966c494c-wpk2t                                   100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  default                    aditum-portal-dev-5c69d76bb6-n5d5b                                100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  default                    aditum-vtexapi-5c758fcfb7-rhvsn                                   100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  default                    admin-mongo-dev-7d9f7f7d46-rrj42                                  100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  default                    mongod-0                                                          200m (21%)    0 (0%)      200Mi (7%)       0 (0%)
  kube-system                fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-pgwfx                                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-m7bz    100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource  Requests    Limits
  --------  --------    ------
  cpu       700m (74%)  0 (0%)
  memory    200Mi (7%)  0 (0%)
Events:     <none>
```

All the cluster's pods are stucked.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                             READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
default       aditum-payment-7d966c494c-wpk2t                                  0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
default       aditum-portal-dev-5c69d76bb6-n5d5b                               0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
default       aditum-vtexapi-5c758fcfb7-rhvsn                                  0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
default       admin-mongo-dev-7d9f7f7d46-rrj42                                 0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
default       mongod-0                                                         0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   event-exporter-v0.2.1-5f5b89fcc8-xsvmg                           0/2       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-scaler-7c5db745fc-vttc9                              0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-pgwfx                                         0/2       ContainerCreating   0          16h
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-sz8r8                                         0/2       ContainerCreating   0          16h
kube-system   heapster-v1.5.3-75486b456f-sj7k8                                 0/3       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   kube-dns-788979dc8f-99xvh                                        0/4       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   kube-dns-788979dc8f-9sz2b                                        0/4       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   kube-dns-autoscaler-79b4b844b9-6s8x2                             0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-bgb6   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-m7bz   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-598d75cb96-6nhcd                            0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   l7-default-backend-5d5b9874d5-8wk6h                              0/1       ContainerCreating   0          13h
kube-system   metrics-server-v0.2.1-7486f5bd67-fvddz                           0/2       ContainerCreating   0          13h
```

A stucked pod.

```
Name:           aditum-payment-7d966c494c-wpk2t
Namespace:      default
Node:           gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-m7bz/10.0.0.3
Start Time:     Thu, 27 Sep 2018 20:30:47 -0300
Labels:         io.kompose.service=aditum-payment
                pod-template-hash=3852270507
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger=LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container aditum-payment
Status:         Pending
IP:
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/aditum-payment-7d966c494c
Containers:
  aditum-payment:
    Container ID:
    Image:          gcr.io/aditumpay/aditumpaymentwebapi:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment:
      CONNECTIONSTRING:  <set to the key 'CONNECTIONSTRING' of config map 'aditum-payment-config'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-qsc9k (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-qsc9k:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-qsc9k
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                  From                                                          Message
  ----     ------                  ----                 ----                                                          -------
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m (x1737 over 13h)  kubelet, gke-aditum-k8scluster--pool-nodes-dev-500ebc8b-m7bz  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post `kubectl describe nodes`?  also `kubectl describe pod <pod-not-creating`?

Comment: Have you enabled private google access for your subnet as described here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters?

Comment: @Jukka yes, I did.

Comment: Is the cluster VPC-native? I just tested creating a VPC-native private cluster into a subnetwork with private google access enabled and all kube-system pods started up just fine.

Comment: Yes, I know. I did that. The cluster was working just fine until yesterday. This problem started out of the blue.

Comment: Okay. Private clusters are currently in beta (no SLA), have you been in contact with Google support about the issue?

Comment: @Jukka I'm trying.

Comment: Did you check your default route and the corresponding tags ? As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#ensuring_that_routing_is_properly_configured), private Google Access uses the default route to send traffic to the public IP addresses of Google APIs and GCP services from instances in subnets where Private Google Access is enabled.

Furthermore, the issue might be related to insufficient CPU, so [resizing your cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-cluster)  might address the issue.

Comment: @mehdisharifi it was a silly problem and I got a little embarrassed. After I reach the google cloud support, I realize that my NAT gateway was not working. The route that's the private access use was passing thougth my NAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for taking to long to respond. It was a very silly problem. After I reach the google cloud support, I notice that my NAT machine was not working properly. The PrivateAccess route was passing thougth my NAT. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the description of your nodes, it ca depend from *where* you are launching them.

As mentioned in [kubernetes/minikube issue 2148](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2148#issuecomment-396594247) or [kubernetes/minikube issue 3142](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3142#issuecomment-423402662), that won't work from China.

The workaround in that case is to find another source, pull it and tag it:

```
minikube ssh \
"docker pull registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google-containers/pause-amd64:3.0
docker tag registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google-containers/pause-amd64:3.0 gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0"
```

Comment: I'm launching them from Brazil. So I think that this problem does not apply.

Comment: @ArturFernandes Still, can you do a simple docker pull of that image?

Comment: In my case, I'm using a private GKE. So I use the GCR. In the subnetwork description I can activate a property called PrivateGoogleAccess. The images that I'm trying to pull are all from the GCR.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, and I can make a simple docker pull from my private registry.

Comment: @ArturFernandes OK, so this answer is not for your case. I will leave it here in case it matches the issue of another reader.